# How to find the available screen height for html body using Javascript in Android mobile

Tags: javascript, android, html

Here is the use case:-

Initially I had set the html body height with window.innerHeight  as given below

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.height = window.innerHeight+'px';
```

But with above approach height of body will reduce if window height is reduced. So I want a better approach so that html body can get static available screen height.

Comment: Do you mean the `window.innerHeight` is changed when the device rotates or when the keyboard is displayed?

Comment: When keyboard comes up window.innerHeight is changed

Comment: Correct. But you can set an option in the Manifest to prevent that.

Comment: Options are set BTW what options are you talking about